# Get all the columns back after reduceByKey transformation in spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, transformation, rdd

I am newbie on Stack overflow and to Spark.Basically doing RDD transformation.

My input data :

```
278222631,2763985,10.02.12,01.01.53,Whatsup,NA,Email,Halter,wagen,28.06.12,313657794,VW,er,i,B,0,23.11.11,234
298106482,2780663,22.02.12,22.02.12,Whatsup,NA,WWW,Halter,wagen,26.06.12,284788860,VW,er,i,B,0,02.06.04,123
```

My RDD format

```
val dateCov: RDD[(Long, Long, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Long, String, String, String, String, String, String, Long)]
```

doing some `reduceBykey` transformations map([(k,k),(v)] on col (1,17) as key and col(18) as Value. And applying some functions on reduceByKey

example:

```
val reducedSortedRDD = dateCov.map(r => { ((r._1, r._11) -> (r._18)) })
      .reduceByKey((x, y) => ((math.min(x, y)))) // find minimum diff
      .map(r => (r._1._1, r._1._2, r._2))
      .sortBy(_._1, true)
```

1. My question - Is it possible after `reduceByKey` function to get all the others columns i.e my reducedSortedRDD return type should be `reducedSortedRDD :` `RDD[(Long, Long, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Long, String, String, String, String, String, String, Long)]`

and not `reducedSortedRDD: RDD[(Long, Long, Long)]` as in this case.

2. I am doing it right? I just want basically to have a whole initial RDD instead of a subset of RDD after `reduceByKey` transformation

I am using spark 1.4

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to bring all columns along in your `reduceByKey` function (keep in mind the overhead of shuffling extra data) or alternatively you may be able to join the `reducedSortedRDD` with your original data.

To bring all columns along, you would do something like this:

```
val reducedSortedRDD = dateCov
  .map(r => ((r._1, r._11),(r._18, r._2, r._3, ..., r._17)))
  .reduceByKey((value1,value2) => if (value1._1 < value2._1) value1 else value2)
  .map{case(key, value) => (key._1, key._2, value._2, value._3, ..., value._17, value._1)}
  .sortBy(_._1, true)
```

To do join, it would look something like this:

```
val keyValuedDateCov = dateCov
  .map(r => ((r._1, r._11, r._18), (r._1, r._2,r._3, ...., r._17)))

val reducedRDD = dateCov
  .map(r => ((r._1, r._11), r._18))
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => math.min(x, y)) // find minimum diff
  .map{case(key, value) => ((key._1, key._2, value), AnyRef)}

val reducedSortedRDD = reducedRDD
  .join(keyValuedDateCov)
  .map{case(key, (_, original)) => (key._1, key._2, original._1, original._2, original._3, ..., original._17, key._3)}
  .sortBy(_._1, true)
```

The join version has a weakness in that if multiple rows in the original data has the exact same values in columns 1, 17 and 18, then the end result will also contain multiple rows with those values and thus not properly reduced. If data is guaranteed not to have multiple rows with the same values in these columns, there should be no problem.

Comment: @ Glennie :Thanks for your quick support. With your first option, I was able to solve my problem.

Comment: @ Glennie :Prior to posting this question , I had converted the RDD to Dataframes and carried out the `Join` option(second option). But as you said I had same values and did not help me. I am happy that your first solution worked for me

Comment: @glennie So If I bring along the extra fields, will that be cheaper than reduce and join later? I wanted to avoid join in this case, thinking it will be more costly.   I have similar problem, but I am not able to figure out pyspark equivalent.

Comment: @Sriram please note that this answer is 4 years old - a lot has happened in Spark since and working directly on `rdds` is rarely seen these days. Today I would use `dataframes` and probably do a `groupBy` or maybe use a window function.